Add rotation to all keyframes of existing animation?
I have an idle animation that causes my character's right arm to clip through his pistol holster, and to fix it I manually went through all the keyframes and added the same small adjustment to the shoulder's rotation W. This was quite tedious and I would like to avoid doing this again in the future.
Is there a way to add a rotation 'nudge' to a bone across all keyframes of an existing animation?

Have you tried to do it in the Graph Editor? Select the W rotation track and move it on the editor Y axis

In the Object Properties panel on the right there's a section called Delta Transform. Those settings are specifically for "adding a rotation/location/scale to all other transforms" for an object.

@moonboots just wanted to say thanks, once I figured out what you were talking about it's actually pretty cool. However, if the property I want to animate does not have an F-Curve (say I want to change the Y rotation but the curve only has X), how do I add the curve I need?

Answering my own question: every keyable value has a line in the graph, but the ones that aren't animated will stack up on their default value line. You can cycle through them by repeated clicking the same key. Doing that I found a key for the quaternion W line for spine1, hit L to select linked to get the entire animation, then nudged it around using G. Hope this helps someone!

As suggested by @Jakemoyo, you can use Properties ▸ Object Properties ▸ Transform ▸ Delta Transform section to add "extra" rotation on top of existing rotations, including keyframes. This will not modify your keyframes, but will have the desired effect within Blender.
As suggested by @moonboots, if you edit the animation in the Graph Editor you can select the keyframes and offset them along the Y axis (the values) by a specific amount. In the second half of the screen capture below, I press A to select all the keyframes, G to start moving them, Y to constrain the motion to the Y axis, and then—after sliding the mouse around for fun—I type 45 Enter to move them up by an exact amount.

